# What Magic Hat does in Escape Goat?

Tags: escape-goat

I found a Magic Hat in one of the first 6 levels of Escape Goat. My animal little friend now wear this item but what properties gives to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the magic hat you can press <kbd>v</kbd> to switch places with your magical mouse.

[image: switch]

Image from the [Escape Goat website](http://www.playescapegoat.com/)